# How do I install and use Wordpress GeSHi - Generic Syntax Highlighter

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting, geshi

Can anyone recommend how to install and use wordpress.org GeSHi syntaxhighlighter? I'm looking for start-to-end directions in one place, not a link that refers to info in 8 other "prerequesite" knowledge links.

Comment: Superuser? is that the same as Meta StackOverflow? Can you be a little more helpful here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeSHi official documentation talks about [Installing GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html#installing-geshi) : http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html#installing-geshi.

Answer (score 0):

Your link on GeSHi gave good directions, thanks Moayad.  I chose your answer as best reply to the question.

But I ended up going with Manoli http://manoli.net/csharpformat/ instead. Nothing to install, easy to use.

Comment: Excuse me, but this answer is completely irrelevant to your own question!